# Android layout weight glitches?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm getting some weird glitches when using the layout_weight on my Android app. To make sure that I'm not wasting anybody's time. When I have three custom views and give two views a weight of 1 and one view a weight of 2. The view with a weight of 2 is supposed to be the biggest one, right? Because that ain't happening with me.

Couple of example's with behavior:

- 1:2:1 - view in the middle completely disappears.
- 1.1 : 1.1 : 1 - first two views are slightly smaller than third. (this is what I currently use to get the desired layout.)

Code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <CUSTOMVIEW
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.1" />

        <CUSTOMVIEW
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12.5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"/>

        <CUSTOMVIEW
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Note: I tried giving the customviews a width and height of `0dp`, but than they completely disappear.

Comment: you need make customviews width 0dp and height wrap_content.you can try it

Comment: @abby Just tried it, it makes the customviews disappear.

Comment: sorry , should height 0dp and width wrap_content

Comment: @abby That did it, thank you! Add your answer to the post, so I can checkmark and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make height `0dp` and width `wrap_content` . good job B.Cakir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use layout_weight in your views you must use weight_sum in your parent View. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:weightSum="3.2">

    <CUSTOMVIEW
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.1" />

    <CUSTOMVIEW
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"/>

    <CUSTOMVIEW
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please notice that weight_sum property is the result of 1.1+1.1+1 = 3.2

Comment: Same behaviour.

Comment: Could you kindly remove the id's, please? I forgot to remove them initially.